# Deselect checkboxes in for loop KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to deselect each checkbox that is checked depending on results, but I get an error stating ***boolean is not a function***

**ViewModel**

```
function IndexVM() {
    // Observable objects
    this.Files = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.CreateAML = function () {
        var self = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < self.Files().length; i++) {
            if (self.Files()[i].Selected) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "Home/CreateAML",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: "{ 'File': " + ko.toJSON(self.Files()[i]) + "}",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   success: function (response) {
                       self.Files()[i].Selected(response.d); //this is where the error is thrown
               }
            }

   };
};
```

**UPDATE:**

```
function File() {
    var self = this;
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
    // ...more properties
};

function IndexVM() {
    var self = this;

    // Observable objects
    self.Path = ko.observable();
    self.Files = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.selectedFiles = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Files(), function (file) {
            return file.Selected();
        });
    });

    this.CreateAML = function () {
       var self = this;

       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedFiles(), function (file) {
           $.ajax({
               url: "Home/CreateAMLTest",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: ko.toJSON({
                   File: ko.toJS(file)
               })
           }).done(function (response) {
               file.Selected(response.d);
           }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               // handle the error
           });
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `File.Selected` isn't an observable in your code, it's a plain Boolean value.

Either make it observable or use `self.Files()[i].Selected = response.d;` to set it. I suggest the former.

I also suggest a few other changes to your code:

```
function File() {
    var self = this;
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
    // ...more properties
}

function IndexVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.Files = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.SelectedFiles = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Files(), function (file) {
            return file.Selected();
        });
    });

    this.CreateAML = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.SelectedFiles(), function (file) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home/CreateAML", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: ko.toJSON({
                    File: ko.toJS(file)
                })
            }).done(function (response) {
                file.Selected(response.d);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // handle the error
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Notes:

- `File.Selected` is an observable now.
- For convenience there now is a `SelectedFiles()` computed, I suppose you will need it on other places as well. And if you don't, it's still improving the semantics of `CreateAML()`.
- I switched from a `for` loop to `ko.utils.arrayForEach()`. Doing so has a positive effect on the readability of `CreateAML()` as well, plus [creating functions in a loop (like the callbacks to `.ajax()`) is not recommended in JavaScript](https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop). *(Incidentally, your use of this anti-pattern is best prove for that - you reference `i` in your callback, but at the time the callback runs, `i` no longer contains what you think it contains. Even without the error you encountered your loop would not have behaved correctly.)*
- Building JSON by concatenating strings isn't ideal. Using a pure approach is better (`ko.toJSON({ File: ko.toJS(file) })`.
- I switched from the "success" callback to the "deferred" sematics in the Ajax call.
- Look at the [knockout's mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) if you don't want to map all your objects manually to their view models.
- By overwhelmingly widely adopted convention only *constructor* names are `PascalCase` in JavaScript, all other identifiers are in `camelCase`. So it would be `IndexVM`, but `createAML`, `files` and `selectedFiles`. Think about switching.

Comment: Thank you for the much appreciated info. I am getting the error 'undefined is not a function' at this line: this.selectedFiles = ko.pureComputed(function () {

Comment: What version of knockout are you using? If it is below 3.2, just use `computed()` instead of `pureComputed()`. [Pure computeds](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) have been introduced in 3.2. If you can't use them, never mind and use normal ones.

Comment: I am using 3.0, so my understanding is it should work

Comment: Whoops, my bad, they have been introduced in 3.2. Comment above fixed.

Comment: Thanks that work but now I am getting the same error that boolean is not a function in the computed function: return file.Selected();

Comment: It seems you have missed the point of my answer. Your `File.Selected` *must be an observable* for that and obviously it isn't.

Comment: I see you copied my code to your question. How is that an update? It's all really very simple. You get this error when `Selected` is not an observable. **That's all there is to it.** Look at how you create `File` objects and make the necessary changes.

Comment: Yes I took your advise and made that changes like you suggest to my code as well so it will look the same. How can Selected not be an observable if it is an observable in the File object?

Comment: My guess is because you overwrite it by setting `file.Selected = true` at some other point in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68642/discussion-between-g-man-and-tomalak).